# Improving a processor design in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, design, cache, processor

For a project at my university we have to improve the design of a processor (more specifically, the [Plasma CPU](http://plasmacpu.no-ip.org/). The design is generated based on a description written in VHDL.

We have to identify weak spots in the design and improve them. The most obvious points that can be improved are the are the multiplier (the default multiplier takes 32 cycles) and the clock speed (which requires lowering the delay encountered on the critical delay path).

Currently, I'm trying to improve the cache, but I found this to be very complicated (but it could just be my lack of experience with hardware projects). I tried to improve the cache by using cachelines of 4 words instead of 1, but I am unsuccesful in doing so: I can't understand the (undocumented) protocol that the DDR controller follows and every attempted change results in the DDR controller refusing to read or in corrupted data.

Is there a plan of attack for understanding and/or improving hardware design in VHDL? I think one of my problems is that the improvement I want to implement requires changes in a lot of modules (DDR controller, memory controller, cache, CPU and changes in signals in some higher-level modules) and I can't comprehend all of them at the same time. Also, I was hoping that there might be easier targets for improvement (besides the multiplier and the critical delay path).

If anyone wants more information, just ask.

Comment: Plan of attack: 1) Identify problem. 2) Fix it. 3) Repeat.

Comment: An improvement implies a prior weakness. Can you find a weakness? A weakness in a CPU is often an imbalance, like one stage of a pipeline requiring (much) more time than the others, or a lot of resources spent on a seldom-used feature, or an often-ocurring sequence of instructions that could be implemnented as one instruction, etc. And if you want to do anything in this field do read the Hennessy & Patterson books - all of them.

Comment: For my diploma i mad a processor with an FPU, including floating point division. You can try it :)

Comment: For this project, we have to improve the processor on a chosen set of benchmarks, we can't expand it (so adding opcodes wouldn't help either). Sounds like an interesting project though!

Comment: Do you have pipeline and cache? These are the things that improve benchmarks the most.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum yes, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really difficult to respond your question.

You are looking for a methodology that could help you to solve your system issues, but this point is unclear due to the flexibility of HDL. You can plan a high optimized system but with a lot of interactions between parts or you can optimize each part isolating them from the rest of the system and well-defining their interactions with the rest of the system.

I have seen how the HDL system architectures have been changed through the last years. The tendency is create isolated modules and connect them with memory mapped interfaces as Wishbone or AXI. In your case, I think you can't use this kind of buses but you can apply the strategy of **isolate parts and limit and well-define their interactions**. This way will help you to simulate parts independently of the rest of the system and find localized bugs and bottle necks to improve them.

I wish this response could help!

Best regards

Comment: I understand my question is vague and I appreciate your effort to answer it! This indeed seems like a good idea. Another thing that has helped me, so far, is to not look at the vhdl code directly, but instead make a finite state machine that represents the behaviour of the module.

Comment: Absolutely right. In the design process is useful to move between lower (VHDL code) and higher (FSM diagram) abstraction levels to aim the objectives of the design.